# SPSS percentile issue

Tags: spss

I am working with SPSS 18.
I am using FREQUENCIES to calculate the 95th percentile of a variable.

```
FREQUENCIES SdrelPromSldDeu_Acr_5_0
 /FORMAT=NOTABLE
 /PERCENTILES 1,5,95,99.
```

The result is given in a table

> ```
>     Statistics  
>    SdrelPromSldDeu_Acr_5_0  
>           N Valid   8881  
>           Missing   0  
>  Percentiles    1   -1,001060644014  
>                 5   -1,000541440102  
>                95   6619,140632636228  
>                99   9223372,036854776000
> ```

But if I double-click the 9223372,036854776 to copy it, another number appears: 1.0757943411193715E7.

If I use MEANS to get the maximum value, the result is 2.4329524990388575E8, so the number that appears on the double-click seems possible.

I have seen 9223372,03 in other cases as well, as if it were some kind of upper limit SPSS is able to display.

Can anybody tell me if the 9223372,03 represents anything useful? Should I trust the bigger number?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in the display of SPSS.
The number you have shown is eerily similar to
9223372036854775807
which is the highest value possible if a variable is declared as a long integer.
see also:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9223372036854775807

Since your actual number is 11 degrees smaller, it should not reach this limit. Hence the conclusion that it must be a bug in the display software.
Do not trust it.
(the number behind may or may not be right, but the 9223372,03 is surely wrong)